# Laravel orWhereHas not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to use the `orWhereHas` method in Laravel with nested relations, but I am not getting the result I expect. Am I misunderstanding how to use this method?

My relationships are set up as follows:

```
Product
    -> hasOne uniqueItem
        -> hasMany fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems
    -> hasMany skus
        -> hasOne uniqueItem
            -> hasMany fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems
```

I'm trying to test out the `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` methods by retrieving products from the database that contain `uniqueItems` that have a `uniqueItemFulfillmentCenter` with `id = 7089` OR products that contain a  `sku`, that contains a `uniqueItem`, that has a `uniqueItemFulfillmentCenter` with `id = 7412`.

Based on the data in my database, the result of this query should be two products. Product IDs 105 and 239.

Here's the Eloquent code I'm using:

```
$product = Spire_models\Product
    ::whereHas('uniqueItem.fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems', function ($query)
    {
            $query->where('id', 7089);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('skus.uniqueItem.fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems', function ($query)
    {
            $query->where('id', 7412);
    })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

For some reason, this is only returning product ID 105, instead of 105 and 239. The generated sql from this function is:

```
select * from `products` where `products`.`deleted_at` is null and (select count(*) from `unique_items` where `products`.`unique_item_id` = `unique_items`.`id` and (select count(*) from `fulfillment_center_unique_items` where `fulfillment_center_unique_items`.`unique_item_id` = `unique_items`.`id` and `id` = 7089 and `fulfillment_center_unique_items`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1 and `unique_items`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1 and (select count(*) from `skus` where `skus`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and (select count(*) from `unique_items` where `skus`.`unique_item_id` = `unique_items`.`id` or (select count(*) from `fulfillment_center_unique_items` where `fulfillment_center_unique_items`.`unique_item_id` = `unique_items`.`id` and `id` = 7412 and `fulfillment_center_unique_items`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1 and `unique_items`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1 and `skus`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1
```

Is this sql being generated incorrectly, or am I misusing the `orWhereHas` method? To me it does not look like the `OR` statement is being placed correctly in the sql.

If I remove the `orWhereHas` method, things works as expected. For example, if I run this:

```
$product = Spire_models\Product
    ::whereHas('uniqueItem.fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems', function ($query)
    {
            $query->where('id', 7089);
    })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

I correctly get back product ID 105.  If I run this:

```
$product = Spire_models\Product
    ::whereHas('skus.uniqueItem.fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems', function ($query)
    {
            $query->where('id', 7412);
    })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

I correctly get back product ID 239. So the individual pieces of the query work correctly, but it seems when I try to combine these with an `orWhereHas`, I get unexpected results. Any idea why?

**EDIT**

As per the comments, it looks like this is a bug. I was able to temporarily work around it by rewriting the code to use `where` and `orWhere`.  Here's the temporary solution:

```
$product = Spire_models\Product
    ::where(function ($query)
    {
            $query->whereHas('uniqueItem.fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems', function ($query)
            {
                    $query->where('id', 7089);
            });
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query)
    {
            $query->whereHas('skus.uniqueItem.fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems', function ($query)
            {
                    $query->where('id', 7412);
            });
    })
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Yep, that's a bug. needs fixing

Comment: Thanks @JarekTkaczyk. What should I do here? Report the issue in Github?

Comment: Yes, please report the issue. I already made a fix, just need to adjust the tests and will push a PR tomorrow.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Have you fixed this in the meantime? If yes please add a short answer. Thanks

Comment: @lukasgeiter There you go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug and is fixed by now with this PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8171

It's been OK since version **5.0.21**